# How can I format dots in tableofcontents like this picture?

Tags: table-of-contents

How can I format dots in tableofcontents like this picture?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the standard definition of `\dottedtocline` from latex.ltx:

```
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

We need to shift every second line here.  A way to do it is to introduce a flag (say, `\ifshiftdots`), and make the `\dottedtocline` toggle it.  If the toggle is true, we shift the dots by half period, otherwise we do not:

```
\makeatletter
\newif\ifshiftdots
\shiftdotsfalse
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
  \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
  {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
   \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
   \interlinepenalty\@M
   \leavevmode
   \@tempdima #3\relax
   \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
    {#4}\nobreak
    \ifshiftdots
      \global\shiftdotsfalse
      \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu
                           \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}$}\hfill
     \else
       \global\shiftdotstrue
       \leaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern \@dotsep mu
                            \hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \fi
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
   \par}%
  \fi}
  \makeatother
```

Comment: How can I compile? I can not get the dots.

Comment: Add the code to the preamble of the document